# Species Distribution modelling incorporating climate data in R

Tags: r, spatial, dismo

I am trying to use data from GBIF to get an idea of Vachellia species disturbution across Africa and overlay this with annual rainfall in R.

Any package advice, online resources or tutorials would be greatly appreciated?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not easy to see what you have in mind, but you may try

- Chloropleth: sf, rnaturalearth, ggplot (geom_sf), maps
- Openstreetmap: ggmap (`get_stamenmap(bbox = bbox, zoom = 5, maptype = "toner-lite")`)
- Spatial smoothing: mgcv (`gam_gp = target ~ te(lat, long, m = list(c(3,.5)), d=2, bs = 'gp'), data = data_dt, cluster=cl, method = "REML")`
- Spatial regression

Other packages may be useful as well, on the top of my mind: leaflet, tmap, gganimate

see:

- [using spatial data in R](https://cengel.github.io/R-spatial/)
- [Geocomputaion with R](https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/)
- [Species distribution modelling](https://www.rspatial.org/raster/sdm/index.html)
- [R-spatial](https://www.r-spatial.org/)
- [Nice example of spatial smoothing with GAMs](https://m-clark.github.io/generalized-additive-models/appendix.html)

Have fun